# GWT execute Liquibase script on server start

Tags: java, gwt, liquibase

I'm getting started with GWT. I manage the database with Liquibase and I want to execute its chagelog on the server start but I don't know how to do it. I did some research on the internet but nothing. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

GWT has almost nothing to do with server side. It is a compiler to produce JS from java code which is run in browser consuming sevices from any kind of backend (rails, php, java, etc). When your backend is Java, GWT provides a few utilities for changing java objects between server and client.

So, and guessing that you want to run your app in a server container, you can use any standard way used in java backends to run something on the startup, a simple way is to use the init of a servlet:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.FooServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


public class CrunchifyExample extends HttpServlet {
  public void init() throws ServletException {
     // your code here
  }
}
```